# Problem with static data member - fixing linking error creates a compiler error

Tags: c++, static, linker, linker-errors, mingw32

game.h:

```cpp
enum Game_state { MAIN_MENU, /*...*/ };
namespace list { class Linked_list { public: Linked_list() {} }; }

class Game {
    public:
        static Game_state state;
        static list::Linked_list<Obj> objs;
};

Game_state Game::state = MAIN_MENU;
list::Linked_list<Obj> Game::objs = list::Linked_list<Obj>();
```

This gives me the linker error: `multiple definition of Game::state (and Game::objs)`.

If I take out the type specifiers it gives me the compiler error: `'state' in 'class game' does not name a type (same for objs)`.

All I need is to initialize these members.

I'm using mingw on 32 bit windows 10.

Comment: The static member definitions belong in a source file (`.cpp`), not the header (`.h`). Please show a full [repro].

Comment: If you define variables or functions in a header file, they will be defined in each and every [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) that included the header file. Functions and variables needs to be defined only once.

Comment: On another note, `list::linkedlist<obj> game::objs = list::linkedlist<obj>();` is effectively the same as `list::linkedlist<obj> game::objs;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move those definitions into a translation unit (cpp file). Otherwise you will redefine them every time you include the header file somewhere, violating ODR.

Comment: I don't think that's the case (I use include guards, #ifndef etc etc), but I'll try.

Comment: @lenerdv that has nothing to do with include guards. Include guards only prevent duplication within one translation unit but not across multiple translation units. They deal with a different kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Put the definitions of 'game::stat' and 'game::objs' in a *.cpp file and link against it.